About convergence in $C^\infty_c$ and $C^\infty$
We work withing an open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Clearly we have $C^\infty_c \subset C^\infty$. These spaces have quite difficult topologies but the required tools are the following:
On $C^\infty$:
A sequence $\{\phi_i\}$ is said to converge to zero if for all compact $K \subset \Omega$ and any multiindex $\alpha$ we have $$\sup_{x \in K}|D^\alpha \phi_i| \rightarrow 0,  \ \ \ \ i \rightarrow \infty.$$
On $C^\infty_c$:
A sequence $\{\phi_i\}$ is said to converge to zero if there exists a compact set $K \subset \Omega$ such that $\text{supp } \phi_i \subset K$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$ and for all multiindex $\alpha$ we have $$\sup_{x \in K}|D^\alpha \phi_i| \rightarrow 0 ,\ \ \ \ i \rightarrow \infty.$$
The difference seems pretty clear and it is easy to see that if $\{\phi_i\}$ converges in $C^\infty_c$ then it converges in $C^\infty$.
Now consider the following example:
For $\phi \in C^\infty_c$ different from zero, we define $\phi_j(x) = \frac{\phi(x-j)}{j}$. This sequence converges to zero pointwise. However, it doesn't convergence in $C^\infty_c$ because the support of $\phi_j$ is getting translated by $j$ meaning that it is impossible to choose a single compact set that contains all the supports of $\{\phi_j\}$.
Now it's the part that I am not sure: Can I claim that $\phi_j \rightarrow 0$ in $C^\infty$? Because the convergence in this space considers all compact sets $K$ and we know that $\Omega = \bigcup_i K_i$ (each $K_i$ a compact set). Therefore, since we are translating the support of each $\phi_j$, there will be some compact set such that $K \cap \text{supp }\phi_j = \emptyset$ for big enough $j$.
Can anyone help me phrasing this in a way that makes the distinction between the convergence in each space clearer?
Another question: Does the same reasoning apply to $\phi_j(x) = j\phi(x-j)$?
Thank you.

$\phi (x-j)=0$ if $x-j \notin \operatorname{supp} (\phi)$. If $K$ is a compact set, then $K$ is disjoint from $j+\operatorname{supp} (\phi)$ whenever $j$ is sufficiently large. Hence, $\phi_j$ is identically $0$ on $K$ for $j$ sufficiently large. It follows that $\phi_j \to 0$ in $C^{\infty}$. The same argument works for $j\phi (x-j)$ also.

Thank you very much. If I may, the fact that we have no convergence in $C^\infty_c$ is because we can't find a single compact set $K$ that contains all supports?

Yes, that is correct.  @user57
